# Problem In Animation On Brackeys Tutorial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I've been following Brackeys's tutorial on how to make a video game in Unity3D. Up to now things have been great.

But now when I create a game over screen and animated it, it keeps on looping when it triggers. I've tried turning off loop time and transitioning to an empty state with no exit time. It also doesn't loop the whole thing just around less than half a second.

My EndTrigger script and CompleteLevel script is below. I don't get any debugging errors.

```
using unityEngine;
public class EndTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameManager gameManager;

    void OnTriggerEnter ()
    {
        gameManager.CompleteLevel();
    }
}
```

My CompleteLevel Script Below

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelComplete : MonoBehaviour {
    public void LoadNextLevel ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: One is looking for local method LevelComplete the other a component  CompleteLevel and looks for a local variable of gameManager so this is not your complete code or yes it will not do what you expected as gameManager is not defined and you aren’t calling the component you made

Comment: so are you saying its because gamemanager is not defined or because or CompleteLevel and LevelComplete are different?

Comment: All of the above theres so much wrong there it’s no surprise it’s not working. Your GameManager has no CompleteLevel code. The component LevelComplete is not used nor called so if this is truly your code. No it wont compile and wont work

Answer (score 0):

In your project files select the animation file and make sure you've turned off Loop Time. Unity enables it by default.

Comment: i already had it off so no luck here